# Image not found in assets after resize using mogrify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am experiencing a very weird error.

My website was working perfectly, but I had to resize some images on the landing page because too heavy and they were slowing down my page.

I used mogrify to resize all images in app/assets/images

```
mogrify -resize 50% *.jpg
```

After resizing, I deleted all assets using

```
rake assets:clean
```

then

```
rake assets:precompile
```

to recompile images in assets pipeline, however now images are not shown anymore, even though I clear the cache of the browser. If I change the name of the image and in my view accordingly, everything works.

**UPDATED:**

The problem is that when I resize the image, the compiled file name changes. This is the error I get when I try to access the image:

```
No route matches [GET] "/assets/image-small-05a31635ef97c8b04eaeb6e5f3f9053f1146ed1cae0796aed876f086f934cf0b.jpg"
```

But in asset path, the same file has name:

```
image-small-a8859704b69e18b59af2760e724b27560d1d40a597595308241845f563197a27.jpg
```

So, the random part change on the filesystem but didn't change in the webpage.

Thanks for your help

Comment: My first guess is a caching issue. Did you try reloading the webpage while skipping the cache? Does mogrify change the modified time of the files? I guess it should. Otherwise use `touch` to do that. Are the mogrified images accessible through their asset path? (i.e. paste the src directly in the browser's address bar and see what happens)

Comment: I forgot to say that I always clear the cache. Mogrify change the update time of the file, so this is not the problem. The problem is that after resizing, the compiled image filename changes, whereas the reference in the webpage is the old one. I will update to answer to clarify the issue

Comment: Which cache do you clear? Make sure you clear both the Rails.cache and the browser cache. No other ideas, sorry.

Comment: How do I clean the Rails cache? I am just cleaning the browser cache actually

Comment: `Rails.cache.clear` in a Rails console, for example.

Comment: I tried rake tmp:clear and it looks likw it is working, please add an answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using the correct asset path helpers etc. since your assets successfully showed up prior to mogrification.

Please make sure there is no cache referring to outdated versions of your assets.

- Delete your web browser's cache (force-reload does the same)
- Delete already precompiled assets with `rake assets:clean`
- Delete all metadata on your server with `rake tmp:clear`
- Delete entries in Rails.cache (e.g. memcache) with `rake cache:clear`

Stop (and restart) any Ruby preloader like Zeus, if you are using one.

Finally, restart your Rails application server.

That should bring your assets back online.